# Rails creating reply for message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it right approach to create a form with hidden fields like this:

```
#show.html.haml
= semantic_form_for @reply do |f|
      = f.hidden_field :sender, :value => @message.sender_id
      = f.hidden_field :receiver, :value => @message.receiver_id
      = f.hidden_field :title, :value => @message.reply_title
      = f.input :content, :as => :text
      = f.submit

#private_messages_controller.rb
  def show
    @message = PrivateMessage.find(params[:id])
    @message.read! if @message.receiver == current_user
    @reply = PrivateMessage.new
  end

  def new
    @message = PrivateMessage.new
  end

  def create
    @message = PrivateMessage.new params[:private_message]
    @message.sender = current_user
    if @message.save
      redirect_to user_path(@message.receiver), :notice => "Wiadomość została wysłana"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

to make a reply for a private message, or there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, this is the right approach because all the variables you use as hidden field are linked to a specific form and not to some kind of session so this is the good way to store these I think

Answer (score 1):

I have learned from experience that hidden fields are usually a sign of an incorrect approach.

In this case, for sender I would look at scope, in this case using the relationship and then constructs like `current_user.message`

I would make message_Type (values private and public) a variable of flag, not a different Model.

So my approach would probably be to get the models right first and then build on them.

Comment: I don't agree with the fact that hidden fields are an incorrect approach when all the variables are secured like this... Any user can send a private message to anyone, why do you think this is "incorrect" ?

Comment: It's about the architecture.  Yes hidden fields might work but when you use rails and start not using it's conventions and methods like scope then it's a poor approach to software development that will lead to "A rails application written with a PHP approach".  Please do not consider it a personal criticism, it's more a comment on the architectural approach.  Obviously it takes more of a ruby and rails book (and there are many) to really explain this fully.  If you can explain why you prefer hidden fields to scopes I am all ears :)

Comment: I don't have any idea how would scopes fit in here, maybe you can write an example?

Comment: @Michael Durrant I don't see either how would scopes help on a new entity like this one. I don't prefer the "hidden fields" way, that's the only way I knew in fact, have you got some references on the web explaining this ?
What's more, I don't understand why you tell it's a PHP approach, I'm used to most of the modern Rails conventions and the hidden fields are used in many screencasts (like Ryan Bates' for instance) and books I know too.

Comment: no problem. I'll just disagree.  too busy for extended chat. thx